# Detect and mount SD Card automatically

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I have an ubuntu running on a rasperry pi. A sd-card-reader is connected via USB.
While the gui (gnome) is running, sd-cards are automatically mounted to `/media/ubuntu/{label}` and unmounted appropriately. So the system is technically able to detect sd-card insertion and removal.

In production, the rasp pi cannot have a monitor attached, kde is not running. I can detect inserted USB-sticks with a udev-rule as taken from https://gist.github.com/juancarlospaco/7f4eab1b6899c55ea90dc0ef5eea965d, boils down to:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="ntfs", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemd-mount --no-block --automount=yes --collect /dev/%k '/media/ubuntu/%E{dir_name}'"


# clean up after device removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemd-umount -l '/media/ubuntu/%E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/bin/rmdir '/media/ubuntu/%E{dir_name}'"
```

It works fine for usb-sticks. But not with sd-cards. Not very surprising, since udev does not trigger add or remove, just change. In the session below, sd-card was removed and inserted again.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ udevadm monitor

KERNEL[6751.389160] change   /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
UDEV  [6751.599761] change   /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
KERNEL[6754.242775] change   /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
UDEV  [6754.391038] change   /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc (block)
```

Polling for block devices is set properly.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /sys/module/block/parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs
2000
```

What can I do here? I want to restate: with gnome, automatic mount/unmount works.